# get dataframe slice with list of column names where not all columns are in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

consider `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((2, 3)), columns=list('abc'))
df
```

[image]

```
col_list = list('bcd')

df[col_list]
```

generates an error

> ```
> KeyError: "['d'] not in index"
> ```

How do I get as many of the columns as I can?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about using [Index.intersection()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html)?

```
In [69]: df[df.columns.intersection(col_list)]
Out[69]:
     b    c
0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0

In [70]: df.columns
Out[70]: Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')  # <---------- Index
```

**Timing:**

```
In [21]: df_ = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [22]: df_.shape
Out[22]: (200000, 3)

In [23]: df.columns
Out[23]: Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')

In [24]: col_list = list('bcd')

In [28]: %timeit df_[df_.columns.intersection(col_list)]
100 loops, best of 3: 6.24 ms per loop

In [29]: %timeit df_[[col for col in col_list if col in df_.columns]]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.69 ms per loop
```

let's test it on transposed DF (3 rows, 200K columns):

```
In [30]: t = df_.T

In [31]: t.shape
Out[31]: (3, 200000)

In [32]: t
Out[32]:
   0       1       2       3       4        ...    199995  199996  199997  199998  199999
a     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0   ...       1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0
b     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0   ...       1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0
c     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0   ...       1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0

[3 rows x 200000 columns]

In [33]: col_list=[-10, -20, 10, 20, 100]

In [34]: %timeit t[t.columns.intersection(col_list)]
10 loops, best of 3: 52.8 ms per loop

In [35]: %timeit t[[col for col in col_list if col in t.columns]]
10 loops, best of 3: 103 ms per loop
```

**Conclusion:** almost always list comprehension wins for smaller lists and Pandas/NumPy wins for bigger data sets...

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
df[[col for col in list('bcd') if col in df.columns]]
```

this yields:

```
     b    c
0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`Index` object supports [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html#pandas.Index.isin):

```
In [4]:    
col_list = list('bcd')
df.ix[:,df.columns.isin(col_list)]

Out[4]:
   b  c
0  1  1
1  1  1
```

So this will generate a boolean mask of your existing columns against the passed in list

**Timings**

```
In [5]:
df_ = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)
%timeit df_[df_.columns.intersection(col_list)]
%timeit df_[[col for col in col_list if col in df_.columns]]
%timeit df_.ix[:,df_.columns.isin(col_list)]

100 loops, best of 3: 12.8 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 18.6 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 26.6 ms per loop
```

This is the slowest method but its fewer characters and maybe easier to understand

Comment: I asked the question because it's one those annoying things that got me when I started using pandas. I think this answer is super useful an I suspect many would choose it over the others.